# Editable grid bug when loading from html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I noticed very unpleasant behavior while using [editable table](http://www.editablegrid.net/) and sorting on those tables.

When a table is [loaded from HTML](http://www.editablegrid.net/editablegrid/examples/attach/index.html) and you sort a column and then edit a field, the value from default sorting is loaded instead.

But when the same [table is loaded from XML](http://www.editablegrid.net/editablegrid/examples/minimal/index.html)/JSON/JavaScript, this works perfectly - you sort by a column and edit correct value.

I've discovered, that rows have their unique ID and when you sort the table, all `<tr>` elements are sortet with their ID's as well. (But of course when table is loaded from HTML, ID's of `<tr>` don't move and stay on same position.)

Since I didn't find a solution, I'm asking you, if you stumble upon this issue or maybe have an idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a solution at [github](https://github.com/webismymind/editablegrid/issues/23) where this problem was reported.

There are old files on http://www.editablegrid.net, so download sources from Github instead. With these new files is this functionality working properly.